# Testing a range against multiple criteria in IF formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, formulas

I have a range of cells that must be one of the below values:

- 01
- 02
- 04
- 05
- 06
- 07
- 08
- 99

and cannot be blank.

I have a *traffic light* cell at the top above the heading (in cell **R2**), and I am trying to write a *traffic light* formula in cell **R2** so that the cell is Red if any of the range **R4:R223** doesn't match one of the above. If they all match then it must be green.

I have this formula in the *traffic light* cell (R2) at the moment and it works if R4 doesn't contain one of the values:

```
=IF(AND(R4<>"01",R4<>"02",R4<>"04",R4<>"05",R4<>"06",
R4<>"07",R4<>"08",R4<>"99"),CHAR(251),CHAR(252))
```

(Char(251) is a wingdings *cross*, and char(252) is a wingdings *check* or *tick*)

so what's supposed to happen is if I change the values in R4:R223 to not match that list, then there should be a cross in the cell, and this in turn will kick off the Red conditional formatting rule.

And I have this formula in the conditional formatting of the entire range (and it works):

```
=AND(R4<>"01",R4<>"02",R4<>"04",R4<>"05",R4<>"06",R4<>"07",R4<>"08",R4<>"99")
```

So how do I use this formula in the `IF` statement to return `Char(251)` when one of the cells in the range doesn't match the list or is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into SUMPRODUCT. It is very powerful and helpful in these situations. So first I would use this formula in the Traffic Light Cell.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($R2:$R11="01")+($R2:$R11="02")+($R2:$R11="03")+($R2:$R11="04")+($R2:$R11="05")+($R2:$R11="06")+($R2:$R11="07")+($R2:$R11="08")+($R2:$R11="99"))>221, CHAR(252), CHAR(251))
```

This will check all cells in R against your values. If all of them match, then SUMPRODUCT will return 222 (your max number of cells). If the number is above 221 then the IF statement will return TRUE and will then return the check.

I would then remove the `IF` portion of the statement and add `=TRUE` at the end for the conditional formatting portion. 
`=SUMPRODUCT(...)>221=TRUE`

Comment: Thanks for your help; but I tried 

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($R4:R223="01")+($R4:R223="02")+($R4:R223="03")+($R4:R223="04")+($R4:R223="05")+($R4:R223="06")+($R4:R223="07")+($R4:R223="08")+($R4:R223="99"))>220, CHAR(251), CHAR(252))` 

(for rows 4 to 223, total 220 rows to check) and it dowsn't work. When I change say, cell R10, cell R2 (where the traffic light formula is) doesn't change

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer what I am trying to do. The conditional formatting aspect of the *traffic light* cell (**R2** is that if the cell=Char(251), which is a cross, show red fill, else green fill

Comment: I believe your `>220` is too high since the maximum cells is 220 so you will never get greater than 220. set it to 219 or say `<220`. It worked for me but I only used a small sample of data. Also ensure your R column is formatted as text since the `"02"` is checking its value against a string and not an integer.